# Searching Cobol Source Library for DB2 table name

Tags: debugging, cobol

I want to know which all codes in the Production source library uses table A . and performs select and update query.

For example I have PDS HLQ.PROD.SOURCE which has 1000 cobol codes. I have a table A .I want to know which all codes uses table A and and want the report in the form of excel,detailing which all uses insert,select and update query.

SRCHFOR is very time consuming and manual effort.Can any utility be developed to ease out this task.

Comment: Have you talked to your DBAs? Of course you can write a utility, but try for an easy and accurate way first.

Comment: What platform, What database ???. For DB2 (if there is no dynamic SQL) it holds this information in "System tables"

Comment: And what does your title have to do with what you want?

Comment: You need to reply by updating your question or using comments. If you contact your DBAs (or colleagues) you will discover that what @BruceMartin has said is entirely accurate

Answer (score 0):

You can run SUPERC in batch mode to search for the string for "TABLEA".  The IBM standard ISPF options menu has it on panel 3, options 14 and 15 I believe.  Just select batch execution.

The job steps will look something like:

```
//SEARCH  EXEC PGM=ISRSUPC,PARM=(SRCHCMP,'ANYC MIXED') 
//NEWDD  DD DISP=SHR,DSN=YOUR.SOURCE.LIBRARY           
//OUTDD  DD SYSOUT=*                                   
//SYSIN  DD *                                          
SRCHFOR  'TABLEA'                                      
/*
```

Getting it into an Excel spreadsheet format, CSV, is a little trickier.  But the above will give you source members and line numbers and you can set other options to only print lines with values.  You can write a simple post-processor that will create a CSV or use another too -- SORT, FILEAID, et al, to convert those lines for you.